# Why ΔH has two separate equation in my textbook?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heat

[image]

**ΔQ = ΔU + Δ(PV)** (First law of thermodynamics) which has the same statement as the 1st equation.

**$Q_p$ or ΔH= ΔU + PΔV** which is the heat exchanged at constant pressure.

Then why in the image above in my textbook . ΔH has two equations?

Comment: Youtube has Feinmann’s lectures on physics - audio you mught find them wirth listening to.

Comment: $\delta$ H is only for constant pressure. There is never a change in pressure for $\delta$ H.

Comment: @Srijan $\Delta (p\cdot V) $ is equal to the work ($dW$) done/extracted from a system. Because the pressure is constant the work is equal to the pressure times the change in volume .

Comment: @NMech Right that is. I meant to say there is only one equation for $\delta$ H where pressure is const. Not changing unlike the 1st equation of image. Since that equation is the 1st law of thermodynamics

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question. $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (pV)$ is the more generic, while  $\Delta H = \Delta U + p\Delta (V)$ is a subcase when pressure is constant..

Comment: Ok. @SolarMike It is said in textbook that $q_p$ of $\delta$H = U2 + PV2 - PV1. Here , it true that pressure is constant. Then , why do we say that $\delta$ H= $\delta$ U + 0. Here , can we also say that when pressure is constant. Work done = 0.

Comment: @SolarMike ok. I have understood my Q.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Good - now that you understand it, please post the answer.

Comment: Ok. @DaleM I’ll post in some time. Busy rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the answer to my Q.

ΔH=ΔU+Δ(pV)is the general statement for Δ q and ΔH

Whereas , ΔH=ΔU+pΔ(V)
is a subcase when pressure is constant.